# Lookup values corresponding to the closest date

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `x` with `date` and `Value`

```
x = structure(list(date = structure(c(1376534700, 1411930800, 1461707400, 
1478814300, 1467522000, 1451088000, 1449956100, 1414214400, 1472585400, 
1418103000, 1466176500, 1434035100, 1442466300, 1410632100, 1448571900, 
1439276400, 1468382700, 1476137400, 1413177300, 1438881300), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(44L, 49L, 31L, 99L, 79L, 92L, 
10L, 72L, 60L, 41L, 28L, 21L, 67L, 61L, 8L, 65L, 40L, 48L, 53L, 
90L)), .Names = c("date", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

and another list `y` with only `date`

```
y = structure(c(1470356820, 1440168960, 1379245020, 1441582800, 1381753740
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

Before I try to do it with a loop, I wanted to find out if there is a quick way (or packages) to lookup `Value` from the closest date in `x` for dates in `y`? The goal is to find out a `date` in `x` that is closest to the `date` in `y` and obtain the corresponding `Value`.

The desired output (*got from Excel* `VLOOKUP`*, so may not be perfect*) would be something like:

```
output = structure(list(y = structure(c(1470356820, 1440168960, 1379245020, 
1441582800, 1381753740), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    Value = c(40, 65, 44, 65, 44)), .Names = c("y", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `x$Value[which.min(x$date - y)]`

Comment: You haven't provided a desired output, maybe `library(data.table) ; setDT(x)[data.table(y), on = .(date = y), roll = "nearest"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(y, function(z) x$Value[which.min(abs(x$date - z))])
# [1] 40 65 44 67 44
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` you can join to the nearest value

```
library(data.table)

x <- as.data.table(x)
y <- data.table(date=y)

res <- x[y, on='date', roll='nearest']
```