# Finding closest matching time for each patient

Tags: r, dataframe, time, logic

I have two sets of data:

First set:

```
 patient<-c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
 arrival<-c("11:00","11:00","13:00","13:00","14:00","14:00","14:00","14:00")
 lastRow<-c("","Yes","","Yes","","","","Yes")

 data1<-data.frame(patient,arrival,lastRow)
```

Another set of data:

```
 patient<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
 availableSlot<-c("11:15","11:35","11:45","11:55","12:55","13:55","14:00","14:00","14:10","17:00")

 data2<-data.frame(patient, availableSlot)
```

I want to create add a column to the first dataset such that for each last row of each patient, it shows the available slot that is 
closest to the arrival time:

The results would be:

```
  patient arrival lastRow availableSlot
       A   11:00        
       A   11:00     Yes     11:15
       B   13:00        
       B   13:00     Yes     12:55
       C   14:00        
       C   14:00        
       C   14:00        
       C   14:00     Yes     14:00
```

Would appreciate if anyone can tell me how I can implement this in R.

Comment: you'll probably need to convert your columns with hours to date class first

Comment: so this? `merge(data1, data2[!duplicated(data2$patient),], by = 'patient')` assuming your `data2` is ordered by `arrival`

Comment: @Sotos No, that's just lucky. OP said "closest" which happens to coincide with first here.

Comment: ahh... I missed the closest part

Answer (score 8):

I'd use data.table, first cleaning up by converting to ITime and ignoring redundant rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)[, arrival := as.ITime(as.character(arrival))]
setDT(data2)[, availableSlot := as.ITime(as.character(availableSlot))]
DT1 = unique(data1, by="patient", fromLast=TRUE)
```

Then you can do a "rolling join":

```
res = data2[DT1, on=.(patient, availableSlot = arrival), roll="nearest", 
  .(patient, availableSlot = x.availableSlot)]

#    patient availableSlot
# 1:       A      11:15:00
# 2:       B      12:55:00
# 3:       C      14:00:00
```

*How it works*

The syntax is `x[i, on=, roll=, j]`.

- `on=` are the merge-by columns.
- It's a join: for each row of `i`, we are looking for matches in `x`.
- With `roll="nearest"`, the final column in the `on=` is "rolled" to its nearest match.
- The `on=` columns in the original tables can be referenced with `x.*` and `i.*` prefixes.
- The `j` argument should give a list of columns, and `.()` is an alias for `list()` here.

Check out the package's introductory materials at http://r-datatable.com/Getting-started and type `?data.table` for the docs relevant to rolling joins.

---

I would stop at `res`, but if you really want it back in your original table...

```
# a very nonstandard step:
data1[lastRow == "Yes", availableSlot := res$availableSlot ]

#    patient  arrival lastRow availableSlot
# 1:       A 11:00:00                  <NA>
# 2:       A 11:00:00     Yes      11:15:00
# 3:       B 13:00:00                  <NA>
# 4:       B 13:00:00     Yes      12:55:00
# 5:       C 14:00:00                  <NA>
# 6:       C 14:00:00                  <NA>
# 7:       C 14:00:00                  <NA>
# 8:       C 14:00:00     Yes      14:00:00
```

Now, `data1` has `availableSlot` in a new column, similar to when you do `data1$col <- val`.

Comment: brilliant explanation +1!

Comment: Great explanation as always

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  May I ask what x in x.availableSlot is?

Comment: @Headandtoes Sure. If you look at the docs by typing `?data.table`, you'll see that the syntax is `x[i, ...]` and the columns that are being joined on (in `on=`) can be referred to using `x.*` or `i.*` notation to take them from the respective tables. These are useful because `x.colname` and `i.colname` may be different in a rolling join like this one (and a few other special cases).

Comment: Hi, also just wondering if the time format is changed to "02Aug2016 11:15:00", the conversion to ITime no longer works.  Can someone help ?

Comment: @Headandtoes Yeah, for that, you'll want `as.ITime(as.POSIXct("02Aug2016 11:15:00", format = "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S"))` or just stick with the POSIXct instead of extracting the time. For relevant documentation, see `?strptime`. If you don't want to fiddle too much with date-time formats, you could also try the `anytime` package which seems to reliably guess the relevant `format`.

Comment: I now have another set of data with this format "08/04/2016 18:45", how do I use the conversion to ITime?

Comment: @Headandtoes Read the `?strptime` documents and/or use the anytime package to convert to a POSIX datetime, then convert to ITime using as.ITime.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (based on [joel.wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41730080/7128934) to my question) that will work with base `R`

```
#Convert dates to POSIXct format
data1$arrival = as.POSIXct(data1$arrival, format = "%H:%M")
data2$availableSlot = as.POSIXct(data2$availableSlot, format = "%H:%M")

#Lookup times from data2$availableSlot closest to data1$arrival
data1$availableSlot = sapply(data1$arrival, function(x)
                    data2$availableSlot[which.min(abs(x - data2$availableSlot))])

#Keep just hour and minutes
data1$availableSlot = strftime(as.POSIXct(data1$availableSlot, 
                                origin = "1970-01-01"), format = "%H:%M")
data1$arrival = strftime(as.POSIXct(data1$arrival), format = "%H:%M")

#Remove times when lastrow is empty
data1$availableSlot[which(data1$lastRow != "Yes")] = ""
```