# Finding closest time across two datasets in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, comparison

I have two datasets:

```
 patient<-c("A","A","A","B","B")
 time<-c("24Nov2016 14:05:00","25Nov2016 14:51:00","26Nov2016 21:57:00","24Nov2016 00:55:00","24Nov2016 11:55:00")
 DS1<-data.frame(patient,time)
```

Another dataset:

```
 patient2<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
 time2<-c("24Nov2016 14:06:00","25Nov2016 14:52:00","26Nov2016 15:57:00","26Nov2016 21:57:00","24Nov2016 00:54:00","24Nov2016 03:59:00","24Nov2016 11:59:00")
 DS2<-data.frame(patient2,time2)
```

For each row in the first dataset (DS1), I want to find the closest time2 if the patient is the same in DS1 and DS2

Results:

```
   patient     time                closestTime
      A    24Nov2016 14:05:00      24Nov2016 14:06:00
      A    25Nov2016 14:51:00      25Nov2016 14:52:00
      A    26Nov2016 21:57:00      26Nov2016 21:57:00
      B    24Nov2016 00:55:00      24Nov2016 00:54:00
      B    24Nov2016 11:55:00      24Nov2016 11:59:00
```

I am new to R so any help would be appreciated. Also, I am not sure if I need to change the data type for the time data field first.

Comment: this shall help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982782/finding-closest-matching-time-for-each-patient

Comment: I am not able to use the answer from the previous post to get the results.  Not sure if it is because it is the timestamp issue, the time variable includes both date and time.