# vlookup approximate date matches in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have two R data frame

```
Factor = data.frame(date = c("2015-10-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-04-01", 
"2016-07-01", "2016-10-01", "2017-01-01"), factor = c(0.07606455, 
0.07170356, 0.07127930, 0.06807735, 0.06764824, 0.06709560))

Factor =
date       factor
2015-10-01 0.07606455
2016-01-01 0.07170356
2016-04-01 0.07127930
2016-07-01 0.06807735
2016-10-01 0.06764824
2017-01-01 0.06709560

Dates = data.frame(date = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-28", "2016-01-29", 
"2016-03-01", "2016-06-02", "2016-07-03", "2016-10-04", "2016-10-05"))

Dates = 
date       
2016-01-01 
2016-01-28 
2016-01-29 
2016-03-01 
2016-06-02 
2016-07-03 
2016-10-04
2016-10-05
```

I am looking for a Excel type Vlookup for approximate match. I cannot do R `merge` function as the dates are not exact. 
Also I cannot match index like in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729888/lookup-values-corresponding-to-the-closest-date) or using min date differences like below

```
apply(Dates, 1, function(x) min(which(abs(x - Factor$date) == min(abs(x - Factor$date)))))
```

Since I require the factor from Factor data frame, which is less than or equal to date from Dates dataframe. 
My desired output should be

```
Output = 
date       factor  
2016-01-01 0.07170356
2016-01-28 0.07170356
2016-01-29 0.07170356
2016-03-01 0.07170356
2016-06-02 0.07127930
2016-07-03 0.06807735
2016-10-04 0.06764824
2016-10-05 0.06764824
```

Is there any efficient way other than looping to achieve the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Dates)[, date := as.IDate(date)]
setDT(Factor)[, date := as.IDate(date)]
Factor[Dates, on = "date", roll = Inf]
#          date     factor
# 1: 2016-01-01 0.07170356
# 2: 2016-01-28 0.07170356
# 3: 2016-01-29 0.07170356
# 4: 2016-03-01 0.07170356
# 5: 2016-06-02 0.07127930
# 6: 2016-07-03 0.06807735
# 7: 2016-10-04 0.06764824
# 8: 2016-10-05 0.06764824
```

For each date in `Dates` this will match the lower/equal-nearest date in `Factor` and get its `factor`

Comment: Well, that's what you get for not providing data that can be conveniently copied. Try `dt1[dt2, on = "date", roll = -Inf]`.

Comment: Got the desired solution by `dt1[dt2, on = "date", roll = Inf]`. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a data frame with all keys, join values ("factors") where you have them, and use one loop for all (instead of one loop per row)

```
t1 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 3, 6), b=c(1, 1, 2))
t2 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7))
tsum <- data.frame(a=sort(unique(c(t1$a, t2$a))))
tmerge <- merge(tsum, t1, all.x=TRUE)
for (i in c(1:nrow(tmerge))){if(is.na(tmerge$b[i])){tmerge$b[i]=tmerge$b[i-1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the result might not work if in my Dates dataframe the date corresponds to factor in row 1 then to row 3, i.e. skipping one or multiple rows in between.

Comment: you could filter ```tmerge``` for (only) keys in t2 (or in your case, the dates dataframe)