# Speed up date lookup in R

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a vector of dates and matches it with a subset list of dates (based on certain attributes). For example, say my raw data looks like this:

```
key_1 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
date_1 <- as.Date(c("2012-03-31", "2011-01-31", "2011-08-07", "2014-04-09"))
```

And my lookup data looks like this:

```
lookup <- date.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  key_2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
  date_2 = as.Date(c(
             "2010-05-12", "2011-05-12", "2012-05-12", "2013-05-12", 
             "2010-12-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-12-01", "2013-12-01"
           ))
)
```

I'm essentially looking for the largest `date_2` that `date_1` is larger than. So that `date_1` maps to `date_3`. Basically, it's this in Excel:

```
date_3 = VLOOKUP(date_1[1], date_2[1:4], 1, TRUE)
```

Which would produce this:

```
date_3 <- c("2011-05-12", "2010-05-12", "2010-12-01", "2013-12-01")
```

My current function (below) works great but my raw data is 220k rows so it takes roughly 12 minutes to run. While that isn't the worst thing in the world, I was hoping there might be a faster way to run it.

```
my_fun <- function(key_1, date_1) {
   indices <- sapply(unique(lookup$key_2), function(x) {which(lookup$key_2 ==  x)})
   periods <- lookup$date_2[indices[,key_1]]
   index <- findInterval(x = date_1, vec = periods) %>% as.numeric()
   periods %>% magrittr::extract(index)
}

date_3 = mapply(my_fun, key_1, date_1, USE.NAMES = FALSE) %>% 
  as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Thanks.

Update: I've tried utilizing both of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729888/lookup-values-corresponding-to-the-closest-date?rq=1) but couldn't get them to work.

Comment: Your example for `date_3` is really hard to figure out.  You pass one date as the first arg, 4 dates (what are they?  you never gave us a *variable* named `date_2,` only a column of `lookup`) and you get 4 dates back.  What's the rule?

Comment: `date_3` is simply the result of looking up each observation of `date_1` in `date_2`. It subsets `lookup` using `key_1` for said observation and then matches `date_1` with the largest value of the subsetted `date_2` that `date_1` is larger than.

Comment: can it be that `date_3[1]` should be `2011-05-12` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.